# Flutter import error: System couldn't find path in custom template

Tags: import, path

i got a problem where it seems like my "import" cant find the path everytime i get

lib/Utils/CustomSnackBar/CustomSnackBar.dart:3:8: Error: Error when reading 'Constants/style.dart': System couldnt find path.

import '../../../Constants/style.dart';

but i checked it many time already. Everything seems right... Did i forgett anything?

Its a template that i got...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVPiM.png)

I already tried to change the path or write it out but it doesnt change anything....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.